# ios 8.1 calling AudioConvertFillComplexBuffer make a infinite loop with cpuload 100%

Tags: infinite-loop, ios8.1, audiotoolbox, audio-converter

I'm converting audio by using the `AudioToolBox.AudioConverter` library.

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription inDescription;
inDescription.mSampleRate = 44100;
inDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3;
inDescription.mFormatFlags = 0;
inDescription.mBytesPerPacket = 0;
inDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1152;
inDescription.mBytesPerFrame = 0;
inDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
inDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 0;
inDescription.mReserved = 0;

AudioStreamBasicDescription outDescription;
audioDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM
audioDescription.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian;
audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
audioDescription.mBytesPerPacket = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame = sizeof(SInt16)*audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 8 * sizeof(SInt16);
audioDescription.mSampleRate = 44100.0;
```

This is the conversion part with mp3AudioData...

```
AudioBufferList *mp3Audio = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + sizeof(AudioBuffer));

mp3Audio->mNumberBuffers = 1;
mp3Audio->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels  = 2;
mp3Audio->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = chunkLen;
mp3Audio->mBuffers[0].mData = calloc(chunkLen, sizeof(uint8_t));
memcpy(mp3Audio->mBuffers[0].mData, chunkData, chunkLen);

AudioStreamPacketDescription *packetDescription =
(AudioStreamPacketDescription*)malloc(sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription) * frames);
packetDescription->mDataByteSize = chunkLen;
packetDescription->mStartOffset = 0;
packetDescription->mVariableFramesInPacket = 1;

OSStatus result = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(audioConverter,
                                                  fillComplexBufferInputProc,
                                                  &(struct fillComplexBufferInputProc_t) { .bufferList =mp3Audio, .frames = frames, .packetDescriptions = packetDescription },
                                                  &frames,
                                                  pcmAudio,
                                                  NULL);

free(mp3Audio->mBuffers[0].mData);
free(mp3Audio);
free(packetDescription);
```

The first running of `AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer` is OK but when I run that function a second time, the infinite loop happens with cpuload 100%.

This code is OK on an IOS 7 device, but when I run it on an IOS 8 device, the infinite loop happens.

Could anyone tell me why this happens on IOS 8?

`fillComplexBufferInputProc` function:

```
static OSStatus fillComplexBufferInputProc(AudioConverterRef             inAudioConverter,
                                           UInt32                        *ioNumberDataPackets,
                                           AudioBufferList               *ioData,
                                           AudioStreamPacketDescription  **outDataPacketDescription,
                                           void                          *inUserData) {
    struct fillComplexBufferInputProc_t *arg = inUserData;

    for (int i = 0; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++) {
        ioData->mBuffers[i].mData = arg->bufferList->mBuffers[i].mData;
        ioData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = arg->bufferList->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize;
    }

    if (NULL == *outDataPacketDescription) {
        *outDataPacketDescription = arg->packetDescriptions;
    }

    *ioNumberDataPackets = arg->frames;

    return noErr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it seems no possible infinite loop in your code (except for-loop in `fillComplexBufferInputProc` function), I suggest you use Instruments (Time Profiler) to see what method is using the majority of CPU time. Check the stack trace for more information, so maybe we can help. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) is a tutorial for time profiler.